# The confusing nature of $f(x) = x^{x^{x^{...}}}$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, fake-proofs

A few months ago, I encountered the following problem:
$$x^{x^{x^{...}}} = 2$$

The simple solution is as follows:
$$x^{2} = 2 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt{2}$$.

I also discovered the following:
$$x^{x^{x^{...}}} = 4 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt[4]{4} = \sqrt{2}$$

But $2 \neq 4$ and therefore this seems wrong.

On further research, I found that $\frac{1}{e} \leqslant x^{x^{x^{...}}} \leqslant e$ and thus the second case of the equation is invalid.
However, I was never really able to gauge why these bounds have been set and why one cannot set values for $x^{x^{x^{...}}} > e$. 
Other than graphically, I have seen no proof for the same and would greatly appreciate any such proof or intuition that would help put things into perspective.

Comment: Have you read: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05559.pdf ?

Comment: You define the expression as $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ where $a_{n+1}=x^{a_n}$, now the gist is that for any $a>e$ there exista a $b<a$ such that $a^{1/a}=b^{1/b}$, and the sequence sticks to be rather than to $a$. For the given example it's easy to see that $a_n$ is increasing and yhen induction shows $a_n<2$ so $a_{n+1}=\sqrt 2^a_n <\sqrt 2^2=2$. The case where $1/e\leq a \leq 1$ is more complex I'd assume it could be argued by looking at $x^a=a$ and solving it for $a$, but that isn't solvable in elementary functions and I don't have time right now to examine properties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be in how your formula is proved.  If we let $a$ be the tower of x's then after raising x to the power of the LHS and RHS we get

$x^a=x^2$.  The LHS is 2 so we get $2=x^2$.

In your second equation you most likely did $2^a=2^2$, but $2 \neq x$.